# Populating every nth row in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a pandas dataframe, df defined as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year':[1,2,3,...],'A':[2000,4000,6000,...],'B':[200,400,600,...]})
```

where 'Year' goes from 1-40 but it can be any integer n.
I want to calculate a new column as follows

```
df['C'] = 0.06*(df.A + df.B]
```

However I wish to calculate column C only for years

```
years = [3,5,7,10]
```

i.e. I only want to perform the calculation when

```
Year in [3,5,7,10,13,15,17,20,...]
```

for the first 50 years (assuming the dataframe has that many rows; in my case, the last year is 40)

Comment: What have you tried?  pandas magic indexing can do this in several ways.  You can do `df[df['Year'] in [3,5,7,10,13,15...]]` to pick those rows, or you can use `.loc`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```py
# Required imports
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Year':[1, 2, 3],
        'A':[2000, 4000, 6000],
        'B':[200, 400, 600]
    }
)

# List of yers you want to compute `0.06 * (df.A + df.B)`
years = [3, 5, 7, 10]


# When Year value exists inside the `years` list defined above, perform the calculation
# Otherwise, set it to None.
# NOTE: chnage the third parameter (None) to some default value you want to
#       use when the year value is not contained inside your list.
df['C'] = np.where(df['Year'].isin(years), 0.06 * (df.A + df.B), None)
#                  ^---------------------^ ^------------------^ ^---^
#                  |                       |                    |
#                  +--- Condition          |                    +--- What to set when condition is not met.
#                                          +---- What to set when condition is met
df
# Returns:
#   Year     A    B      C
# 0     1  2000  200   None
# 1     2  4000  400   None
# 2     3  6000  600  396.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
years = [3,5,7,10]
# filter rows matching the year, and calculate C

df.loc[df['Year'].isin(years), 'C']=0.06*(df.A + df.B)
df
```

```
    Year    A   B   C
0   1   2000    200     NaN
1   2   4000    400     NaN
2   3   6000    600     396.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
years = np.ravel([np.array([3,5,7,10]) + 10*i for i in range(4)])
df['C'] = np.where(df['Year'].isin(years), 0.06*(df.A + df.B), np.nan)
```